# Best way to extract TimeZone object from a String?

Tags: java, timezone

I have a database field that contains a raw date field (stored as character data), such as

> Friday, September 26, 2008 8:30 PM Eastern Daylight Time

I can parse this as a Date easily, with SimpleDateFormat

```
DateFormat dbFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aa zzzz");
Date scheduledDate = dbFormatter.parse(rawDate);
```

What I'd like to do is extract a TimeZone object from this string. The default TimeZone in the JVM that this application runs in is GMT, so I can't use `.getTimezoneOffset()` from the `Date` parsed above (because it will return the default TimeZone).

Besides tokenizing the raw string and finding the start position of the Timezone string (since I know the format will always be `EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aa zzzz`) is there a way using the DateFormat/SimpleDateFormat/Date/Calendar API to extract a TimeZone object - which will have the same TimeZone as the String I've parsed apart with `DateFormat.parse()`?

One thing that bugs me about `Date` vs `Calendar` in the Java API is that `Calendar` is supposed to replace `Date` in all places... but then they decided, oh hey let's still use `Date`'s in the `DateFormat` classes.

Comment: did u got solution for this issue?

Comment: Regarding last paragraph, the `Date` & `Calendar` classes are a bloody mess: poorly-designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them. Use the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes instead.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the following:

```
        DateFormat dbFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aa zzzz");
        dbFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
        Date scheduledDate = dbFormatter.parse("Friday, September 26, 2008 8:30 PM Eastern Daylight Time");
        System.out.println(scheduledDate);
        System.out.println(dbFormatter.format(scheduledDate));
        TimeZone tz = dbFormatter.getTimeZone();
        System.out.println(tz.getDisplayName());
        dbFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
        System.out.println(dbFormatter.format(scheduledDate));
```

Produces the following:

```
Fri Sep 26 20:30:00 CDT 2008
Friday, September 26, 2008 08:30 PM Eastern Standard Time
Eastern Standard Time
Friday, September 26, 2008 08:30 PM Central Daylight Time
```

I actually found this to be somewhat surprising. But, I guess that shows that the answer to your question is to simply call getTimeZone on the formatter after you've parsed.

Edit:
The above was run with Sun's JDK 1.6.

Comment: I was also surprised by this and have run into issues with TimeZone sliding due to Date instantiation before.

Comment: Just curious - what is the result of TimeZone.getDefault() on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

@Ed Thomas:

I've tried something very similar to your example and I get very different results:

```
String testString = "Friday, September 26, 2008 8:30 PM Pacific Standard Time";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aa zzzz");

System.out.println("The default TimeZone is: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());

System.out.println("DateFormat timezone before parse: " + df.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());

Date date = df.parse(testString);

System.out.println("Parsed [" + testString + "] to Date: " + date);

System.out.println("DateFormat timezone after parse: " + df.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
```

Output:

> The default TimeZone is: Eastern Standard Time
>
> DateFormat timezone before parse: Eastern Standard Time
>
> Parsed [Friday, September 26, 2008 8:30 PM Pacific Standard Time] to Date: Sat Sep 27 00:30:00 EDT 2008
>
> DateFormat timezone after parse: Eastern Standard Time

Seems like `DateFormat.getTimeZone()` returns the same TimeZone before and after the `parse()`... even if I throw in an explicit `setTimeZone()` before calling `parse()`.

Looking at the source for DateFormat and SimpleDateFormat, seems like `getTimeZone()` just returns the TimeZone of the underlying Calendar... which will default to the Calendar of the default Locale/TimeZone unless you specify a certain one to use.

Comment: java version "1.4.2_14"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.4.2_14-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.4.2_14-b05, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out the **Joda Time date and time API**. I have recently been converted to a believer in it as it tends to be highly superior to the built-in support for dates and times in Java. In particular, you should check out the **DateTimeZone** class. Hope this helps.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html

Comment: The *Joda-Time* project is now in maintenance mode. Its principal author, Stephen Colebourne, went on to lead JSR 310 and its implementation, the *java.time* classes in OpenJDK, the successor to Joda-Time.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.parse( 
    "Friday, September 26, 2008 8:30 PM Eastern Daylight Time" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEEE, MMMM d, uuuu h:m a zzzz" ) 
).getZone()
```

## java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes. The Question and other Answers use the troublesome old legacy date-time classes or the the Joda-Time project, both of which are now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Define a `DateTimeFormatter` object with a formatting pattern to match your data.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEEE, MMMM d, uuuu h:m a zzzz" );
```

Assign a `Locale` to specify the human language of the name-of-day and name of month, as well as the cultural norms for other formatting issues.

```
f = f.withLocale( Locale.US );
```

Lastly, do the parsing to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
String input = "Friday, September 26, 2008 8:30 PM Eastern Daylight Time" ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2008-09-26T20:30-04:00[America/New_York]

You can ask for the time zone from the `ZonedDateTime`, represented as a `ZoneId` object. You can then interrogate the `ZoneId` if you need more info about the time zone.

```
ZoneId z = zdt.getZone();
```

[See for yourself in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/vYSd3M).

## ISO 8601

Avoid exchanging date-time data in this kind of *terrible* format. Do not assume English, do not accessorize your output with things like the name-of-day, and never use pseudo-time-zones such as `Eastern Daylight Time`.

For time zones: Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

For serializing date-time values to text, use only the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The java.time classes use these formats by default when parsing/generating strings to represent their value.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well as a partial solution you could use a RegEx match to get the timezone since you will always have the same text before it.  AM or PM.

I don't know enough about Java timezones to get you the last part of it.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between Date and Calendar is, that Date is just a value object with no methods to modify it. So it is designed for storing a date/time information somewhere. If you use a Calendar object, you could modify it after it is set to a persistent entity that performs some business logic with the date/time information. This is very dangerous, because the entity has no way to recognize this change.
The Calendar class is designed for operations on date/time, like adding days or something like that.

Playing around with your example I get the following:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class TimeZoneExtracter {

    public static final void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat dbFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aa zzzz");
        System.out.println(dbFormatter.getTimeZone());
        dbFormatter.parse("Fr, September 26, 2008 8:30 PM Eastern Daylight Time");
        System.out.println(dbFormatter.getTimeZone());
    }

}
```

Output:

> sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Berlin"...
>   sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Africa/Addis_Ababa"...

Is this the result you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Ed has it right.  you want the timeZone on the DateFormat object after the time has been parsed.

```
 String rawDate = "Friday, September 26, 2008 8:30 PM Eastern Daylight Time";
 DateFormat dbFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aa zzzz");
 Date scheduledDate = dbFormatter.parse(rawDate);

 System.out.println(rawDate); 
 System.out.println(scheduledDate); 
 System.out.println(dbFormatter.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
```

produces

```
Friday, September 26, 2008 8:30 PM Eastern Daylight Time
Fri Sep 26 20:30:00 CDT 2008
Eastern Standard Time
```

Comment: You might want to test with something other than "Eastern Daylight Time" in the date String - dbFormatter.getTimeZone() is just returning the default (your) timezone.