# How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project

Tags: android, datetime, android-gradle-plugin, threetenbp, threetenabp

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.2 and my Java setup is the following:

```
>java -version
> openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~15.10.1-b14)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

<sup>I searched for hours trying to figure this out. The answer came from a combination of related answers, so I figured I would document what I learned for anyone else who may be struggling. See answer.</sup>

Answer (score 230, accepted):

## Attention: This answer, while technically correct, is now out of date

#### Java 8+ API desugaring support now available via Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0+

(Also see [Basil Bourque's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61603915/2065427))

Development on the [ThreeTenABP Library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) is winding down. Please consider switching to Android Gradle plugin 4.0, java.time.*, and its core library desugaring feature in the coming months.

To enable support for these language APIs on any version of the Android platform, update the Android plugin to 4.0.0 (or higher) and include the following in your module’s build.gradle file (from [this section of the Java 8 support page on the Android Developers site](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring), which also has additional information on desugaring):

> ```
> android {
>   defaultConfig {
>     // Required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
>     multiDexEnabled true
>   }
>
>   compileOptions {
>     // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
>     coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
>     // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
>     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>   }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>   coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.5'
> }
> ```

---

## Original Answer

### First Discovery: Why You Have To Use *ThreeTenABP* Instead of *java.time*, *ThreeTen-Backport*, or even *Joda-Time*

This is a really short version of the VERY LONG PROCESS of defining a new standard. All of these packages are pretty much the same thing: libraries that provide good, modern time handling functionality for Java. The differences are subtle but important.

The most obvious solution would be to use the built-in [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package, since this is the new standard way to deal with time and dates in Java. It is an implementation of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), which was a new standard proposal for time handling based on the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

However, `java.time` was introduced in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8). Android up to [Marshmallow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Marshmallow) runs on Java 7 ("Android N" is the first version to introduce Java 8 language features). Thus, unless you're only targeting [Android N *Nougat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Nougat) and above, you can't rely on Java 8 language features (I'm not actually sure this is 100% true, but this is how I understand it). So `java.time` is out.

The next option might be [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), since [JSR 310](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) was based on Joda-Time. However, as the [ThreeTenABP readme](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP#why-not-use-threetenbp) indicates, for a number of reasons, Joda-Time is not the best option.

Next is [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), which back-ports much (but not all) of the Java 8 `java.time` functionality to Java 7. This is fine for most use cases, but, as indicated in the [ThreeTenABP readme](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP#why-not-use-threetenbp), it has performance issues with Android.

So the last and seemingly correct option is [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### Second Discovery: Build Tools and Dependency Management

Since compiling a program -- especially one using a bunch of external libraries -- is complex, Java almost invariably uses a ["build tool"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) to manage the process. [*Make*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)), [*Apache Ant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant), [*Apache Maven*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), and [*Gradle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) are all build tools that are used with Java programs (see [this post](https://technologyconversations.com/2014/06/18/build-tools/) for comparisons). As noted further down, Gradle is the chosen build tool for Android projects.

These build tools include dependency management. Apache Maven appears to be the first to include a centralized package repository. Maven introduced the [Maven Central Repository](https://search.maven.org/), which allows functionality equivalent to php's `composer` with Packagist and Ruby's `gem` with rubygems.org. In other words, the Maven Central Repository is to Maven (and Gradle) what Packagist is to composer -- a definitive and secure source for versioned packages.

### Third Discovery: Gradle Handles Dependencies in Android Projects

High on my to-do list is to read the Gradle docs [here](https://gradle.org/getting-started-gradle/), including their free eBooks. Had I read these weeks ago when I started learning Android, I would surely have known that Gradle can use the Maven Central Repository to manage dependencies in Android Projects. Furthermore, as detailed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26630422/2065427) StackOverflow answer, as of Android Studio 0.8.9, Gradle uses Maven Central Repository implicitly through Bintray's JCenter, which means you don't have to do any extra config to set up the repo -- you just list the dependencies.

### Fourth Discovery: Project Dependencies Are Listed in [project dir]/app/build.gradle

Again, obvious to those who have any experience using Gradle in Java, but it took me a while to figure this out. If you see people saying "Oh, just add `compile 'this-or-that.jar'`" or something similar, know that `compile` is a directive in that build.gradle file that indicates compile-time dependencies. [Here's](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) the official Gradle page on dependency management.

### Fifth Discovery: ThreeTenABP Is Managed by Jake Wharton, not by ThreeTen

Yet another issue I spent too much time figuring out. If you look for ThreeTen in Maven Central, you'll only see packages for `threetenbp`, not `threetenabp`. If you go to the [github repo for ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), you'll see that infamous `compile 'this-or-that'` line under the Download section of the Readme.

When I first hit this github repo, I didn't know what that compile line meant, and I tried to run it in my terminal (with an obvious and predictable failure). Frustrated, I didn't return to it until long after I figured the rest out, and finally realized that it's a Maven Repo line pointing to the `com.jakewharton.threetenabp` repo, as opposed to the `org.threeten` repo. That's why I thought the ThreeTenABP package wasn't in the Maven repo.

### Summary: Making it work

Now it all seems pretty easy. You can get modern time handling functions in an Android project by making sure your `[project folder]/app/build.gradle` file has the `implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.1'` line in its `dependencies` section:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.ahuman.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.1'
}
```

Also add this to Application class:

```
public class App extends Application {    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AndroidThreeTen.init(this);
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great post. However, I wonder whether you have considered [JodaTimeAndroid](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) as well.

Comment: @Bob, I haven't experimented with JodaTimeAndroid, but only because I'm not really working on anything right now that requires it. From what I remember, the `java.time` implementation was fine (being basically a port of JodaTime), and I'm sure that in another year or two, 90% of users will be on Nougat+, making it a viable solution for development.

Comment: @Bob, JodaTime is basically the same as JSR-310 (even basically made by the same guys), except JSR-310 supposedly has fewer design flaws (see [this article](http://blog.joda.org/2009/11/why-jsr-310-isn-joda-time_4941.html), for example). [...continued below]

Comment: @Bob, from my experience in using both libraries, I wouldn't say that I agree with everything made different in JSR-310 compared to Joda (for example, how it distincts "human" time and "machine" time in basically completely different API branches, which makes it annoying when you need to interface with legacy API, as most of them considered "machine", yet majority of logic requires them to be worked with as if they are "human"). But I certainly see why and how these decisions were made, and JSR-310 is certainly more extensible (speaking from experience of writing my own Chronology).

Comment: To clarify the comments… The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework ([JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)) is the official successor to the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project. Both projects are led by the same man, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen). The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to java.time.

Comment: Of late, you have to change that line to be `implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.3'`

Comment: Make sure you call `AndroidThreeTen.init(this)` before using the API, for example in `onCreate()`.See [ThreeTen-Backport error on Android - ZoneRulesException: No time-zone data files registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281808/threeten-backport-error-on-android-zonerulesexception-no-time-zone-data-files).

Comment: the awesome answer implemented in this https://github.com/Tiganimohammad/Android-Date-using-ThreeTenABP

Comment: The [API desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) pages says a “subset of java.time” is supported. Might there be pieces of functionality in *ThreeTenABP* that are not offered by the desugaring feature?

Answer (score 18):

The accepted [Answer by kael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/642706) is correct. In addition, I will mention a couple things, and provide a diagram about obtaining *java.time* functionality.

## *java.time* built into Android 26+

If targeting [Android 26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_8.0_Oreo_(API_26)) or later, you will find an implementation of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) (*java.time* classes) bundled with Android. No need to add *ThreeTenABP*.

## APIs nearly identical

Just to clarify, [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) for Android is an adaptation of the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library that brings most of the *java.time* functionality to [Java 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [Java 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7). This back-port shares nearly an identical API with *java.time*.

Suppose you are now targeting Android earlier than 26, so you use *ThreeTenABP*. Later, your may eventually drop support for these earlier versions of Android, to use the *java.time* classes bundled with Android. When that happens, you need make few changes to your codebase other than (a) switching `import` statements, and (b) changing any calls you made to [`org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html) to use the new conversion methods that were added to the old legacy date-time classes (`Date`, `GregorianCalendar`).

The transition process from *ThreeTenABP* to *java.time* should be smooth and nearly painless.

## When to use which framework

Here is a chart showing the three frameworks, and indicating when to use which one in which scenarios.

**➥ Update:** Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0+ brings a new 4th option, [API desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) to make available a [subset of *java.time* functionality](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) not originally built into earlier Android. See the top of the [main Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/642706) by kael.

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: I am really confused about using date/time in Kotlin as `java.time` is the thing to use, but it's for 26+ only. Then say use ThreeTen and later it is outdated. So, can you please tell me what should I use for a project of API 21? Thanks!

Comment: @RawHasan See my fresh edits to the "About java.time" section at the end. (A) For Android before 26, I suggest you first try the "API desugaring" feature in the latest Android tooling. This gives you much of the *java.time* functionality in earlier Android. (B) If lacking in some feature you need, then fallback to adding the *ThreeTenABP* library to your project, an Android-specific adaptation of the *ThreeTen-Backport* Java library, which also provides most of the *java.time* functionality. The *ThreeTen-Backport* library uses nearly identical API to *java.time*.

Comment: Thanks, @Basil Bourque! I am a new Kotlin developer and all these date-time things have become a huge confusion for me! But I think I've finally figured it out. I've just set up dependency according to Kael's latest edit, and it looks like `java.time` functionalities are now working on my 21 API project.

Answer (score 8):

Add the following in your build gradle (Module level) file in Android Studio:

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.1'
```

**Create the Application class and initialize it like so:**

```
class App : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        AndroidThreeTen.init(this)
    }
}
```